# Hide event from user in calendar

Tags: list, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

How can I hide some event from some user?

I am working on a vacation calendar. User should see only his vacation, head of some department should see all employees' vacation in current department.

I get information from remote DB and want to put it in calendar list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is any column like vacation assigned to than you can create a new view with filter parameter assigned to me. that might help.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose it might help.  I create new list field, which I will record some information and filter on it

Comment: Yes do it that way.